# Is there a way to have google form responses to record in sheets depending on what section of the form is filled out?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I made a form with multiple conditional paths and my response sheet is ungodly I could really use some help.

The way I set up the form has a total of 19 sections

Location Dropdown (we have 3)> Machine dropdown (a total of 15)> A Machine Specific measurement section and Submit.

I split the Measurements sections by machine because, I was hoping I could have each section record numbers into separate sheets. This way I could keep each Machine's data on its own google sheet.

So logically I am trying to get MachineX measurements to record sheet X but, Get Machine Y to record In Sheet Y. Is what I'm looking for feasible/ even possible?

I know I can try and organize the form responses into the sheets manually, but I am trying my best to avoid that, cause its gonna take a lot of time out of the week.

Maybe there is a way to organize the form response sheet to filter the data into their appropriate sheets. 
I am out of my depth and could really use some help.

Comment: Theses are  a combination of Dropdown questions and short answers

Comment: You may be able to use onFormSubmit trigger to capture the data and redistribute it to desire sheets.

Comment: It can be done.  There are multiple ways you could do it.  It can be done purely with code, or code plus a cell function, or just a query cell function.  Or you could filter data as needed.  I'd use a spreadsheet "On Form Submit" trigger, get the answers from the event object, test for which questions were answered and append the answers to different sheets.  But if you have no programming experience, you may want to research the query cell function.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a linked Sheet to the Form and then an Apps Script function that gets the data and prints it into the Sheet.

First you have to create an [Installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers): [On form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) so every time  the form is submitted the Sheet will be updated

---

Once you have your trigger set up, you have to write the function. 
I would suggest you to create variables for each sheet you want your data in.
You can select the sheet by name like: `sheet.getSheetByName("MachineX")`

I recommend setting up the questions in an order that allows you to say:

> From question 1 to 6 -> go to "MachineX"
>
> From question 7 to 19 -> go to "MachineY"

Now you have to iterate over the answers and get the latest responses:
 - If you just want the latest response to the form you could use something like:
 `for (var i = formResponses.length - 1; i < formResponses.length; i++)`